# How to force my table to appear under its sections title

Tags: tables, two-column, elsarticle, appendix, els-cas

My tables in the appendix are appearing above the title, like this:

[image]

How can I keep the title above all tables?

Here is my code

```
\clearpage
\appendix
\begin{appendices}
\chapter{Appendix}
\section{Appendix}

\begin{table*}
\caption{Caption.}
\label{table_My21}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{cCCCCc}
\toprule
            \textbf{Column 1}
                &\textbf{\makecell{Col 2)}}
                &\textbf{Col 3}
                &\textbf{Col 4}
                &\textbf{Col 5}
                &\textbf{Col 6}\\

\midrule
                 bla bla bla             & 1    &2  &3  &4  &5                \\
                 bla bla bla             & 1    &2  &3  &4  &5                \\
                 bla bla bla             & 1    &2  &3  &4  &5                \\
                 bla bla bla             & 1    &2  &3  &4  &5                \\
                 bla bla bla             & 1    &2  &3  &4  &5                \\
                 bla bla bla             & 1    &2  &3  &4  &5                \\
                 bla bla bla             & 1    &2  &3  &4  &5                \\
                 bla bla bla             & 1    &2  &3  &4  &5                \\
                 bla bla bla             & 1    &2  &3  &4  &5                \\
                 bla bla bla             & 1    &2  &3  &4  &5                \\
                 bla bla bla             & 1    &2  &3  &4  &5                \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table*}


\begin{table*}
\caption{Caption.}
\label{table_My41}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{cCCCCc}
\toprule
            \textbf{Column 1}
                &\textbf{\makecell{Col 2)}}
                &\textbf{Col 3}
                &\textbf{Col 4}
                &\textbf{Col 5}
                &\textbf{Col 6}\\

\midrule
                 bla bla bla             & 1    &2  &3  &4  &5                \\
                 bla bla bla             & 1    &2  &3  &4  &5                \\
                 bla bla bla             & 1    &2  &3  &4  &5                \\
                 bla bla bla             & 1    &2  &3  &4  &5                \\
                 bla bla bla             & 1    &2  &3  &4  &5                \\
                 bla bla bla             & 1    &2  &3  &4  &5                \\
                 bla bla bla             & 1    &2  &3  &4  &5                \\
                 bla bla bla             & 1    &2  &3  &4  &5                \\
                 bla bla bla             & 1    &2  &3  &4  &5                \\
                 bla bla bla             & 1    &2  &3  &4  &5                \\
                 bla bla bla             & 1    &2  &3  &4  &5                \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table*}
```

***Edit***

i tried the method Mico suggested, but still same result

here is code

```
\clearpage % start a new page and flush all accumulated floats (if any)
\onepage   % switch to a one-column layout (and start a new page, if nec.)

\appendix  % switch section numbering from 1, 2, ... to A, B, ...

\section{Section} % or some suitable alternative



hi

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
        Col 1 1 & Col 1 2 \\
       Col 2 1  & Col 2 2
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
```

and here is the result

[image]

Comment: 1) Your code is incomplete, since it's not compilable, please show a MWE. 2) You seem not to want your table to float, so you probably shouldn't use the `table` environment.

Comment: Does your document have a two-column layout? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico yes it is based on Elseveir template

Comment: Elsevier provides templates with both one- and two-column layouts. Which layout does your document employ?

Comment: @Mico the 2 columns

Answer (score 0):

(This answer incorporates information, provided by the OP in the comments section, that the document in question uses a two-column layout.)

When LaTeX is in two-column mode, double-wide floats -- i.e., `table*` and `figure*` environments -- are always placed at the *top* of a page. Well, there are ways around this, but they're not exactly elegant.

Since the OP's appendix would appear to consist exclusively of double-wide tables, I suggest taking the following approach:

```
... 

\clearpage % start a new page and flush all accumulated floats (if any)
\onecolumn   % switch to a one-column layout (and start a new page, if nec.)

\appendix  % switch section numbering from 1, 2, ... to A, B, ...

\section{Additional tables} % or some suitable alternative

\begin{table}[h] % note: 'table', not 'table*'
   ...
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h] % note: 'table', not 'table*'
   ...
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: i tried that.. does not work :(

Comment: @asmgx - Can you be a bit more descriptive? *What* doesn't work? Were you able to switch to one-column mode?

Comment: yes for the column mode, it is a single column now.. but the tables are still showing on the top of the page and the title "A. Additional Tables" is at the bottom

Comment: but instead of \onepage i used \onecolumn

Comment: @asmgx - Thanks for catching the mistake. Indeed, I meant to write `\onecolumn`...

Answer (score 0):

placement option `[H]` from the use of package `float.sty`, may meets your requirement:

```
...
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
...
\begin{table}[H]
```

As you are not providing full `MWE`, I've mentioned the package usage only